# CSS positioning 3

Tags: css, positioning

i want "SOL" to be at the center of the left blocks and "SAG" to be at the center of the right blocks. But it either be at the most left or at the most right. How can i make them center of the left and right blocks?

link: http://www.orhancanceylan.com/sgkm

Answer (score 0):

wrap those 3 things in divs with the following attributes

```
display:block;
width:33%;
text-align:center;
float:left;
```